# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" at path "_id" for model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

To preface: I'm relatively new to working with mongoose/express.

I'm trying to make an app where a mongoose Schema called "Space" has an array called "posts" in it. The contents of the array are ObjectId references to another mongoose Schema called "Post". However, every time I make a GET request to the route that is supposed to send back my Space and the posts in it, I get a nasty error. Also, my posts aren't populating my Space.

The Error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "Space"

Here are my routes:

GET

```
app.get('/spaces/:id', (req,res) => {
Space.findById(req.params.id).populate('posts').exec((err, space) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.send(space);
    }
});
```

});

POST

```
app.post('/spaces/:id/posts', (req,res) => {

Space.findById(req.params.id, (err, space) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect('/spaces/:id');
    } else {
        Post.create(req.body, (err, newPost) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                newPost.save();
                space.posts.push(newPost._id);
                res.redirect('/spaces/:id');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

Here are my Schemas:

Post schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

let postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
description: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

Space Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

let spaceSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
description: String,
posts: [
{
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: "Post"
}
]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Space', spaceSchema);

Comment: Check if the `req.params.id` is a valid ObjecId before making the call to findById method `console.log(mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id))`

Comment: Hi! I just tried it, and I got back "true".

Comment: Looks like the `req.params.id` is undefined. Do a console.log(req.params.id)

Comment: I got a string back for req.params.id. It seems to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error,  the id was wrong in params

correct id:

products/updateproductbyid/***60***fp5f46196351c7e381c0085

wrong id:

products/updateproductbyid/***660***fp5f46196351c7e381c0085

code:

```
 await productsModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
{ _id: _id },
newProduct,
(err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    res.send(err);
  } else {
    res.send("changed!");
  }
}
```

error:

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: '660fp5f46196351c7e381c0085' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "products"

Answer (score 0):

ObjectID provided by MongoDB. It is bsonType ID which is a unique id used to store documents inside the collection.

***CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value “:id” at path “_id” for model***

When we get this type of error it means you are sending invalid ObjectId so you need to first check it using regex or mongoose inbuild functions

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

let orderId = null
try {
  orderId = ObjectId(req.query.orderId)
} catch (InvalidObjectIdException) {
  // send invalid orderId
}
```

Also, you can check through regex `let checkForValidMongoDbID = new RegExp("^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$");`.

ObjectId should verify before proceeding request.

```
function isValidObjectID(parameter, name) {
  let checkForValidMongoDbID = new RegExp("^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$");
  return checkForValidMongoDbID.test(parameter)
}
// your controller
app.post('/spaces/:id/posts', (req, res) => {
  if (isValidObjectID(req.params.id) === false) {
    res.send("Please provide correct object id")
    return
  }
  Space.findById(req.params.id, (err, space) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/spaces/:id');
    } else {
      Post.create(req.body, (err, newPost) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          newPost.save();
          space.posts.push(newPost._id);
          res.redirect('/spaces/:id');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
// http://localhost:8080/spaces/324234/post ==> invalid
// http://localhost:8080/spaces/61056c908cca27df3db2e4c9/post ==> valid
```

Comment: code answers without any comment on the code is not considered a good answer, please elaborate on what is happening in the code chunk.